# Get a value from a string from a records in a server script

Tags: google-app-maker

I work on an app with AppMaker and i want to get some value from a records.
I use this :

```
var query = app.models.Device.newQuery();
query.filters.Projet._equals = "project name";
var records = query.run();

for(var i in records){
  var data = records[i];
  console.log(data.Name);
}
```

i would get a value from a field name like :

```
for(var i in records){
  var data = records[i];
  console.log(data.getString("Name"));
}
```

I can do that with a JDBC object but it is not a good way.
There is a way to doing this with records from app maker ?

Thank you

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but I think maybe this will do what you are looking for: `console.log(data['Name']);`.

Comment: It works perfectly . thanks